# code=139 Error[Segmentation Fault] AVL Tree insertion

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have add_node function which is adding nodes to the tree but when I am going skewed say right it gives segmentation fault.

```
template<class T>
class avl{
   private:
      Node<T>* root;
    public:
    //CONSTRUCTOR
       avl(){
           root=nullptr;
       }
//HEIGHT FUNCTION
    int get_height(){
       return get_height(this->root);   
    }
    int get_height(Node<T>* node){
        int l_height,r_height;
        if(node==nullptr){return -1;}
        else{
        l_height=get_height(node->m_left);
        r_height=get_height(node->m_right);

        if(l_height>=r_height){return l_height+1;}
        else{return r_height+1;}
        }
    }
    //BALANCE_FACTOR
    int balance_factor(Node<T>* node){
        return get_height(node->m_left)- get_height(node->m_right);
    }
    Node<T>* ll_rotate(Node<T>* &node){
        Node<T>* temp=nullptr;
        temp=node->m_right;
        node->m_right=temp->m_left;
        temp->m_left=node;
        return temp;
   }
 Node<T>* rr_rotate(Node<T>* &node){
        Node<T>* temp=nullptr;
        temp=node->m_left;
        node->m_left=temp->m_right;
        temp->m_right=node;
        return temp;
    }
    Node<T>* rl_rotate(Node<T>* &node){
        node->m_right=rr_rotate(node->m_right);
        return ll_rotate(node);
    }
        Node<T>* lr_rotate(Node<T>* &node){
        node->m_left=ll_rotate(node->m_left);
        return rr_rotate(node);
    }

//Rebalance Tree
    Node<T>* rebalance(Node<T>* &node){
        int bf= balance_factor(node);
        
        if(bf>1){
            if(balance_factor(node->m_left)>1){
               return rr_rotate(node);
            }else{
               return lr_rotate(node);
            }
        }else if(bf<-1){
            if(balance_factor(node->m_right)<-1){
              return  ll_rotate(node);
            }else{
               return rl_rotate(node);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
   void add_node(T data){
     add_node(data,this->root);
           }
   Node<T>* add_node(T data,Node<T>* node){
            if(node==nullptr){
                Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
                 return new_node;
            }
            if(data>node->m_data){
                node->m_right=add_node(data,node->m_right);
            } else if(data<node->m_data){
                node->m_left=add_node(data,node->m_left);
            }
        /*    int bf= balance_factor(node);
            //ll case
            if(bf>1 && data<node->m_left->m_data){
                return rr_rotate(node);
            }//rr case
            if(bf<-1 && data>node->m_right->m_data){
                return ll_rotate(node);
            }//lr case
            if(bf>1 && data>node->m_left->m_data){
                  return lr_rotate(node);
            }//rl case
             if(bf<-1 && data<node->m_right->m_data){
                  return rl_rotate(node);
            }*/
            return rebalance(node);
    }
```

> node.h

```
template<class T>
class Node{
  private:
  public:
     T m_data;
     Node<T>* m_left;
     Node<T>* m_right;
     
     Node(T data){
        m_data =data;
        m_left=nullptr;
        m_right=nullptr;
     }
};
```

> main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"avl.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  avl<int> a1;
  a1.add_node(20);
  a1.add_node(25);
  a1.add_node(30);  //Error is happening at this point

}
```

The crash happens when I am adding 30. At that point, i have a tree

```
20
 \
  25
   \
    30
```

add_node calls rebalance on the 20 node. The balance factor is -2 and the balance factor of node 25 is -1 which means it calls rr_rotate(node) on the 20 node. That immediately calls ll_rotate(node->m_right) which is on the 25 node. That function has these two lines

temp=node->m_left;
node->m_left=temp->m_right;

since the node is the 25 nodes so node->m_left is null, so temp is null, so temp->m_right is a crash.

How do I encounter this problem?

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes, and locate when and where in your code it happens. It will also allow you to check variables and their values at the point of the crash.

Comment: I have known this fact using the debugger, but I am confused as node->m_left==nullptr so how do I assign right of the temp node to it!

Comment: If you could read the question you would know its not about segmentation Fault but the way this error is happening ! @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Then use a debugger to *step* through the code, statement by statement.

Comment: did that already that's how I knew where the problem is and I don't know the solution so I have posted it here!

Comment: If you want us to help finding the problem, then please try to create a [mcve] to show us. The top-level `add_node` function is missing, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219404/discussion-between-tushar-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: On an unrelated note, you have a very serious logical bug in your code: What happens when `data == node->m_data`?

Comment: if the two cases are not fullfilled it returns the rebalance(node). Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is lying in the checking of the node for rebalancing. In Rebalance Tree function while I am checking for the balance factor of the parent and then checking for parent's left or right child the value used is wrong. It shouldn't be -1 or 1 it should be 0. As it is not necessary that the child of the node that we are performing the rotation on must have a balance factor greater than 1 or less than -1. But it will always be greater than 0.
so if it is greater than 0 in case of the left heavy parent then we ought to perform a rr_rotation[For left-left case] and similarly ll_rotation for a right heavy subtree.
Following is the working function:

```
Node<T>* rebalance(Node<T>* &node){
       int bf= balance_factor(node);
       if(bf>1){
           if(balance_factor(node->m_left)>0){
               return rr_rotate(node);
           }else{return lr_rotate(node);}
       }
       if(bf<-1){
           if(balance_factor(node->m_right)>0){
               return rl_rotate(node);
           }else{return ll_rotate(node);}
       }
       return node;
   }
```